# I'm Declaring an array of objects after creating a Class Album. the variables of the last object keeps overwriting the other objects

Tags: java, arrays, object

Please implement the following four sorting algorithms.

Insertion Sort (in-place)

Bubble Sort

Selection Sort

Quick Sort

Each line of code in these algorithms should be commented to explain its role in your sorting implementations.

These methods should sort a set of integers in descending order. If your sorting method is passed an array containing the  number 3,5 and 1. Your sorting method should return 5,3,1.

I would also like your sorting method implementations to sort Album Objects. Each album object will consist of an artist and an album title, which will both be String Objects. Each sorting method should sort an array of album titles in descending order (by album title).

```
public class Sorting1
{
  static Album alb;

  public static void main (String[] argv)
  {

    Album albs1 = new Album("Kanye West","My Beautiful Dark Twisted Fantasy");
    Album albs2 = new Album("Kanye West","Yeezus");
    Album albs3 = new Album("Kanye West","The Life of Pablo");
    Album albs4 = new Album("Kanye West","Late Registration");
    Album albs5 = new Album("Kanye West","Graduation");

    //create String array of album albTitles
    String[] albTitles = new String[5];
    albTitles[0] = albs1.getAlbumTitle();
    albTitles[1] = albs2.getAlbumTitle();
    albTitles[2] = albs3.getAlbumTitle();
    albTitles[3] = albs4.getAlbumTitle();
    albTitles[4] = albs5.getAlbumTitle();

    //selectionSort
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(albTitles));
}
}

package Assignment1;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Album {

  private static String artist;
  private static String albumTitle;

  public void setArtist(String newArtist) {artist = newArtist;}   
  public String getArtist(){return artist; }

  public void setAlbumTitle(String newAlbum) {albumTitle = newAlbum;}    
  public String getAlbumTitle (){ return albumTitle; }

  public Album (String newArtist){
      artist = newArtist;  
  }

  public Album (String newArtist, String newAlbum){
    artist = newArtist;
    albumTitle = newAlbum;
  }

  public String toString(){
    return "\nArtist: " + artist + " Album Name: " + albumTitle;
  }

  public void print(){
    System.out.println("Artist: " + artist + " Album Name: " + albumTitle);
  }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `keeps overriding the other objects`? I dont see anything that might do that in your `main(..)` function

Comment: You should really do your own homework if you want to be a developer.

Comment: Posting up your entire assignment is unlikely to get you any answers, post a small amount of code and explain the exact problem you are having and how you have already tried to solve it and you'll get more helpful answers

Comment: it's what camickr said below. Declaring those variables as static is your problem

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Album {

  private static String artist;
  private static String albumTitle;
```

Don't define variables as `static`.

This means all instances of the Album class will reference a single variable.

Get rid of the static modifier.